# How to use in my react project npm install flag-icons after install it and pass a ISO code

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project where I have different account with country ISO code and I need to show a flag related to it. I found this package: https://github.com/lipis/flag-icons which was recommended by a senior dev. But after installing it with NPM I do not see anywhere how I can implement the icon component to pass in my code. I did not find any examples and I would be really grateful to see how to use it here considering i am using tailwind:

```
 <Link to={`accounts/${accountInfo.account_number}`} title={accountLabel}>
      <section
        aria-label="Account widget"
        className="account-widget group flex h-14 cursor-pointer justify-between rounded-lg bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow-plain-lg hover:bg-green-secondary-light-200 hover:text-green-primary-1000"
        key={accountInfo.account_number}
      >
        <div className="flex w-112 items-center justify-between gap-6 ">
          <div>
            <div className="font-bold text-green-primary-1000">
              {accountLabel}
            </div>
            <p className="text-gray-primary-1000 group-hover:text-green-primary-400">
              No. {virtualAccountNumberFormatter(accountInfo.account_number)}
            </p>
          </div>
          {isPaymentDetailsUpdated && isAccountFundingInfoEnabled ? (
            <div className="rounded-md bg-yellow-400 py-2 px-4 text-sm">
              Funding details updated
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center gap-1 text-2xl font-medium">
          {currencySymbol?.length && <span>{currencySymbol}</span>}
          <span>{value.replaceAll(currencySymbolPattern, '')}</span>
          <span>
            <ArrowLongRightIcon className="ml-2 h-7 stroke-gray-primary-600 group-hover:stroke-black-primary-1000 group-active:stroke-black-primary-1000" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Link>
```

basically I need to place it before this div

```
  <div>
            <div className="font-bold text-inpay-green-primary-1000">
              {accountLabel}
            </div>
            <p className="text-inpay-gray-primary-1000 group-hover:text-inpay-green-primary-400">
              No. {virtualAccountNumberFormatter(accountInfo.account_number)}
            </p>
          </div>
```